# Remove Portlet Session on page refresh

Tags: portlet

I am storing a list in a Portlet session. I have to remove the Portlet session on a page refresh because it is displaying the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://portals.apache.org/pluto/portlet-1.0-apidocs/

Get the PortletSession and then call `removeAttribute(String name)` to remove the attribute from the session.